# Realurl Extension Error Typo3 Update 4.5 to 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

I've updated a typo3 website from 4.5 to 6.2.9. Now the issues with old extensions are fixed. But now I'm facing an issue with real url extension [ver.1.12.8]. If it's disabled the front end is rendered with no issues. When the extension is enabled it shows this error

`#1294587214: Configuration Error: 404 page "D:/Xampp/htdocs/project125/404-melding.html" could not be found.`

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, that you have the following value in your LocalConfiguration.php

```
[FE][pageNotFound_handling] = READFILE:D:/Xampp/htdocs/project125/404-melding.html
```

With this configuration, TYPO3 handles a pageNotFound event by displaying the content of the file configured (in your case `D:/Xampp/htdocs/project125/404-melding.html`). When the file can not be found, TYPO3 throws an exception with the code `#1294587214`.

Try to check, if the configured 404 HTML page exists in your filesystem and if not, create it. For further debugging purposes you could also set pageNotFound_handling to "true" or "1" to show an error message instead of an individual 404-page.

Also make sure you clear all caches and also the RealURL encode/decode cache.

Comment: ok, now it shows 
unable to determine rootpage_id for the current domain.

Comment: Please check if the configured domains in your TYPO3 Backend pagetree contains a trailing slash and if so, please remove the slash. Also check, if your realurl-configuration file refers to a rootpage_id, that exist. For debugging you could also try to enable RealURL automatic configuration (basic.enableAutoConf) in the extension configuration.

Comment: Does it work if you use basic.enableAutoConf instead of your RealURL configuration file?

Comment: The automatic configuration works fine for TYPO3 sites with only a few extensions. If you have extensions (e.g. tx_news), it is best to create an own RealURL configuration file to control URL generation of extensions. The fact that automatic configuration works fine indicates, that there is something wrong with your previous RealURL configuration (maybe due to the extension upgrade). So if you want to have your own configuration, a good point to start is to create a RealURL configuration from scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67958/discussion-between-hoja-m-a-and-derhansen).